# Upper-bound on the number of edges in the farthest-point voronoi diagram

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, voronoi-diagram

I'm trying to prove that the number of edges in the farthest-point voronoi diagram of $n$ points is upper-bounded by $2n-3$ (as claimed by [Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540779735)). I could only show that $3n - 6$ is an upper bound (not as strict as required), as follows:

I follow the notation below:

- $v$ is the number of vertices in the farthest-point voronoi diagram
- $e$ is the number of edges in the farthest-point voronoi diagram
- $f$ is the number of faces in the farthest-point voronoi diagram

Now I show the following:

1. By adding a new vertex $v_{\infty}$, and connecting all of the diagram's unbounded edges to it, we create a connected planar graph with $v+1$ vertices and the same number of edges and faces.
2. Since now the planar graph is connected, every vertex has a degree of at least 3. Therefore, $2e \geq 3(v + 1)$.
3. Since only points on the convex hull of the $n$-points set have a cell in the farthest-point voronoi diagram, we get that $f \leq n$.
4. Plugging #2 and #3 into Euler's $(v + 1) - e + f = 2$ yields that $e \leq 3n - 6$

This is actually the same upper bound on the number of edges in the closest-point voronoi diagram.
What do I miss in order to get the tighter bound ($2n-3$) for the farthest-point voronoi diagram?
I guess I need to use the tree structure of the diagram, but I don't see how.

[image: farthest point voronoi diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $m$ the extremal points of the convex hulls of the $n$ sites/points. Your third observation can be re-stated as $f=m\le n$. My advice would be to try to obtain a bound on $v$ with respect to $m$, instead of comparing $v$ and $e$.

---

One way to do that is as follows:

**Hint 1:**

> Take a look at the dual to the furthest-point Voronoi diagram, it is a triangulation of the convex hull.

**Hint 2:**

> By definition of the dual, each triangle of the triangle correspond to a vertex in the Voronoi diagram. So you can express $v$ by expressing the number of triangles $t$ in the dual ($v=t$).

**Hint 3:**

> $v=t=m-2$.

**Hint 4:**

> Plug hint 3 and your observation 3 into $(v+1)-e+f=2$... and remember that $m\le n$.